# I need a program for video streaming and interaction

Tags: streaming, live-streaming

I need a program able to do the following:

1) Record webcam on a desktop pc
2) Send video and audio as stream to another program running on a server
3) The program on the server should act like a "proxy cacher", transmitting the live stream to any client would request it (the server is necessary because of bandwidth reasons)
4) Any client would be a silverlight/flash applet capable of reproducing the live stream (RTSP or other, it doesn't matter)
5) Clients should be able to chat within the silverlight/flash applet and pose questions sent back to the server and then back to the desktop pc who started the webcam recording. The Desktop pc should be able to chat and answer back as well.

It seems like a pretty complex application, do you happen to know something vaguely similar that may suits my needs?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the whole process with flash. On the server-side you need *Flash Media Server* or it's free alternative: [RED5](http://red5.org/). The encoding can be done in a flash player but you will get better results with [Flash Media Encoder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/flashmediaencoder/).

There are ready-made solutions addressing the full workflow, *ustream.tv* is just one of them.